# How can you execute a repeating JSoup task which will work even if the app is in background in android

Tags: java, android, background, jsoup, repeat

For my app I need values which are parsed by jSoup from a website and then returned to the user using a notification, these values change ~ every minute, so to be up-todate with the values I set up a task using a handler, this works good when the app is in foreground, but as soon as the user goes to the homescreen the app will return multiple exceptions like e.g. java.net.UnknownHostException or java.net.SocketTimeoutException, in the code this happens when jSoup is connecting to the specified site, I already tried using Services and AsyncTasks instead of threads, but it was always the exact same problem, I also searched for people with similar experiences, but I guess my issue is quite specific.

This is the code for the handler:

```
private final static int INTERVAL = 1000 * 60;
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mHandlerTask = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                wakeLock.release();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (!isUpdating) {
                isUpdating = true;
                App.shouldUpdate = true;
                System.out.println("update");
                final TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(getApplicationContext());
                                TextView priceEditText = loadedLayouts.get(1).findViewById(R.id.priceTextView);
                                TextView increaseEditText = loadedLayouts.get(1).findViewById(R.id.increaseTextView);
                                updatePricesStock(tinydb.getString("current_isin"), priceEditText, increaseEditText);
                             
                        }
                        wakeLock.acquire(2*60*1000L /*10 minutes*/);
                 
                }
                mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask, INTERVAL);
            }
        }
    };
```

and this is the code for the updateStockPrices method (I will not include updatePricesWarrant and updatePricesKnockout since they are essentially doing the same things and also throw the same exceptions)

```
public void updatePricesStock(final String ISIN, TextView priceText, TextView increaseText) {

        final TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(getApplicationContext());
        final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.ls-tc.de/de/aktie/" + ISIN).get();
                    System.out.println(ISIN);
                    increase = doc.selectFirst("#page_content > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.mpe_bootstrapgrid.col-md-8 > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > span:nth-child(3)").text().replace(" ", "");
                    tinydb.putString(ISIN + "notification_price", doc.selectFirst("#page_content > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.mpe_bootstrapgrid.col-md-8 > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > span:nth-child(1)").text() + "€");

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    tinydb.putString(ISIN + "notification_price", "Error Scraping Price");
                }
            }
        });
        if(!thread.isAlive()) {
            thread.start();
        }
        try{
            thread.join();
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(!thread.isAlive()) {
            notificationCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
            System.out.println("done");
            System.out.println(tinydb.getString(ISIN + "notification_price"));
            priceText.setText(tinydb.getString(ISIN + "notification_price"));
            increaseText.setText(increase);
            System.out.println("Text Updated "  + priceText.getText().toString());
            if(tinydb.getBoolean(ISIN + "_notification_status")) {
                Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), App.notificationChannel)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_attach_money_24).setContentTitle(tinydb.getString(ISIN + "notification_name")).setContentText(tinydb.getString(ISIN + "notification_price")).setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX).setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_STATUS).setOnlyAlertOnce(true).build();

                notificationCompat.notify(tinydb.getInt(ISIN + "_notification_id"), notification);
            }
            isUpdating = false;
        }
    }
```

finnally these are the stacktraces I get:

```
W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$3.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:225)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:263)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:217)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:317)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:311)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:207)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:388)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:146)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:900)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:772)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:493)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:429)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:560)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:106)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:734)
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:706)
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:299)
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:288)
        at de.xliquid.stockwatchultimate.MainActivity$4.run(MainActivity.java:266)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket is closed
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket$SSLInputStream.read(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:588)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:145)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:213)
W/System.err:   ... 18 more
```

---

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.onvista.de": No address associated with hostname
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:156)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
        at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:41)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:178)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:144)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:86)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:192)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:144)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:106)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:400)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:333)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:483)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:429)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:560)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:106)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:734)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:706)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:299)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:288)
W/System.err:     at de.xliquid.stockwatchultimate.MainActivity$6.run(MainActivity.java:371)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:74)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:200)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:74)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:135)
W/System.err:   ... 22 more
```

Also this app is solely for me so I don't really bother if the solution isn't the cleanest or drains the battery faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was energy saving mode, if it is turned on the phone won't do requests in background / idle mode, no matter the wakelock, I solved my problem by adding a permission, so the app can request data even when the phone is in energy saving standby.